# Beowulf Cluster

Tags: mining

Can a Beowulf Cluster be designed to mine Etherium and thus do away with the need of 'hard to get' GPU's that are also becoming expensive? I've seen the RasberryPI Beowulf Cluster but I was not able to discern if it can be applied to mining etherium.

Answer (score 1):

It probably can, but it wouldn't be worth it. You won't be able to get too many megahashes in a cost effective way (up front hardware cost + the electricity cost) out of CPUs. Not with Ethereum, maybe with Monero.

Comment: I saw this which prompted my question....which could address the HW cost issue:

Comment: I saw this which prompted my question....which could address the HW cost issue (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_r3z1jYHAc). On Electricity cost, I have good rates out of Canada, Balkans & E. Europe. It's the HW that intrigues me and if truly it can be done; Beowulf cluster.  I note with optimism your use of the word 'probably'.

Comment: I also note with great interest your comment on Monero. I wonder if it would be possible to draw up a list of coins that would definitely be compatible with BC and thus have a BC dedicated mining operation alongside an Etehrium mine, for example, and average out the net results. The point being, dependency on GPU's is diminished somewhat. I'm definitely a noob in crypto but not in business modeling etc.